# How can I employ cluster analysis in R to identify vegetation communities given only presence-absence data?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to use the results of a quadrat-based vegetation survey to identify discrete herbaceous plant communities across a large tract of land. However, no data beyond simple presence or absence of species in a given quadrat was recorded. Is there any way to use TRUE/FALSE values in this context, in lieu of any quantitative data on species abundance or potentially relevant environmental variables? My goal is to produce a figure showing quadrats as points, with clusters of quadrats with similar vegetation assemblages identified graphically.

I can edit this post to include my code thus far, but I've chosen not to include it for now because I don't know if my entire approach is flawed.

The data are currently stored as a .csv, where columns are species, rows are individual quadrats, and cells show either TRUE (for presence in a quadrat) or FALSE (for absence in a quadrat).

Comment: post what you have got it will be easier to make a determination if your on the write track or not

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a mock example using stats::kmeans

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1235)

# Example TRUE/FALSE quadrat data:
quads = matrix(runif(400) > 0.7, nrow = 20)

# convert this to x, y data of TRUE quadrats:
xy = data.frame(which(quads, arr.ind = T))
names(xy) = c('X', 'Y')

# Number of clusters - to be determined by the data/model:
n_clusters = 5
km = kmeans(xy, n_clusters)
centers = data.frame(km$centers)

# add this to the quadrat data:
xy = cbind(xy, cluster=km$cluster)
 
# Plot
ggplot(data=xy) + 
  geom_point(aes(X,Y, col=as.factor(cluster)), size=2) + 
  geom_point(data=centers, aes(X, Y, col=as.factor(row.names(centers))),
             size = 5, shape=13, stroke=3)
```

[image: Example clustering using k-means]

Is that helpful?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the slow reply - I'm in the early part of grad school and the semester hit like a ton of bricks. I'll take a look and write back.